# Best way to update objects with nullable properties with fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm building a simple REST API.
If the object you want to update contains properties that can contain null, what is the best way to define it in fastapi?

When using pydantic.BaseModel, it is not possible to support the usage of not updating if the property does not exist.

example:

```py
from fastapi import Body, FastAPI
from typing import Optional, Literal
import dataclasses

app = FastAPI()

@dataclasses.dataclass
class User:
    name: str
    type: Optional[Literal['admin', 'guest']]

user = User('test_user', 'admin')

class UpdateUser(BaseModel):
    name: str
    type: Optional[Literal['admin', 'guest']]

@app.put('/')
def put(update_user: UpdateUser):
    # In the case of BaseModel, I don't know the difference between the property 
    # that I don't update and the property that I want to update with None,
    # so I always update with None.
    user.name = update_user.name
    user.type = update_user.type
```

I think the simplest way is to use `dict`.

example:

```py
from fastapi import Body, FastAPI
from typing import Optional, Literal
import dataclasses

app = FastAPI()

@dataclasses.dataclass
class User:
    id: int
    name: str
    type: Optional[Literal['admin', 'guest']]

user = User(1, 'test_user', 'admin')

@app.put('/')
def put(body = Body(...)):
    if 'name' in body:
        user.name = body.name
    if 'type' in body:
        user.type = body.type
```

However, in this case, it is not possible to specify the JSON type used for the request like BaseModel.

How can I implement the update process with dict-like flexibility while preserving type information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is a typical patch request.
At the time of update, UpdateUser can receive it, and `update_user.dict(exclude_unset=True)` can receive a dictionary containing only the parts that need to be updated.

example:

```py
from fastapi import Body, FastAPI
from typing import Optional, Literal
import dataclasses

app = FastAPI()

@dataclasses.dataclass
class User:
    name: str
    type: Optional[Literal['admin', 'guest']]

user = User('test_user', 'admin')

class UpdateUser(BaseModel):
    name: str
    type: Optional[Literal['admin', 'guest']]

@app.patch('/')
def patch(update_user: UpdateUser):
    update_user_dict = update_user.dict(exclude_unset=True)

    if 'name' in update_user_dict:
        user.name = update_user.name
    if 'type' in update_user_dict:
        user.type = update_user.type
```

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-updates/#using-pydantics-exclude_unset-parameter